# Abel's equation for the dilog

Tags: nt.number-theory, dg.differential-geometry, cohomology, hyperbolic-geometry, polylogarithms

Abel's identity for the dilogarithm (see the  wikipedia page about polylogarithms)
plays a role in web geometry as it is one of the abelian relations of the
first example of exceptional web (Bol's 5-web) to appear in the literature.

I have heard it is important in other domains (cohomology of SL(3,C), algebraic K-theory, motives ). 
I would like to learn more about it.

I am asking for:

1. Insights on why Abel's identity is relevant in this or that field;
2. References where it plays a role.

---

**Edit.**
I have just learned from this [blog](http://lamington.wordpress.com/) about [Bridgeman's orthospectrum identity](http://lamington.wordpress.com/2009/10/24/bridgemans-orthospectrum-identity/).
Those interest in the question above might want to take a look at it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One basic answer is given by hyperbolic geometry.

Ideal tetrahedra in hyperbolic 3-space $\mathbb{H}^3$ are equivalent (under the action of the automorphism group $PGL_2(C))$ to tetrahedra with vertices $\{0,1,\infty,z\}$, and their volume is given by $D(z)$, where $D(z)$ is the Bloch-Wigner dilogarithm, which is a slightly modified version of the dilogarithm. This amounts to writing down the hyperbolic metric and evaluating an integral, which turns out to be (very close to) $Li_2(z)$ (although it is real valued for complex $z$).

The tetrahedron $\{0,1,\infty,z\}$ is equivalent under $PSL_2(\mathbb C)$ to $\{0,1,\infty,1/(1-z)\}$ and $\{0,1,\infty,1-1/z\}$, and so we get formulae:

$$D(z) = D(1/(1-z)) = D(1 - 1/z).$$

The tetrahedron $\{0,1,\infty,z\}$ is also equivalent to $\{0,1,\infty,1/z\}$, except with an odd permutation of the vertices, and thus: $D(z) = - D(1/z).$

Finally, choose a random point $y$ in the boundary $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ of $\mathbb H^3$. If we take the tetrahedron $\{0,1,\infty,y\}$, we can break it off into $\{0,1,\infty,x\}$ and three other tetrahedra (just like in Euclidean space). Transforming the coordinates of the other three tetrahedra into the standard form gives the 5-term relation:

$$D(x) - D(y)  + D\left(\dfrac yx\right) - D\left(\dfrac {1-x^{-1}}{1-y^{-1}}\right) + D\left(\dfrac {1-x}{1-y}\right) = 0,$$

which gives a proof of Abel's equation.

Let's think some more about a closed hyperbolic 3-manifold $M$. By definition, $M = \mathbb H^3/\Gamma$ for a lattice $\Gamma$ in $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$. Since $\mathbb{H}^3$ is contractible, $M$ is a $K(\pi,1)$ space, and so there is a canonical isomorphism $H_*(M, \mathbb{Z}) = H_*(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$, comparing simplicial homology with the group homology of $\Gamma$. Now $M$ has a fundamental class $[M]$ in $H_3(M, \mathbb{Z})$, which gives an element in $H_3(\Gamma, \mathbb{Z})$ and hence also a class in $H_3(PSL_2(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Z})$.
On the other hand, $[M]$ can be decomposed ("triangulated") into ideal tetrehedra with parameters $z_i$. The set of parameters $[z_i]$ is not unique, however, the only real "move" is the subdivision of tetrahedra, and so associated to $M$ we get an element of the group generated by $[z_i]$ for $z_i$ in $P^1(\mathbb{C})$ and with relations exactly of the form satisfied by $D$ above. This is essentially the definition of the Bloch group. $D$ is a function this group, and this decomposition gives a map from $H_3(PSL_2(\mathbb{C}), \mathbb{Z})$ to the Bloch group.

Note that it is not obvious that the $z_i$ can be taken inside some field $\mathbb{F}$, this is a consequence of Mostow Rigidity. It turns out that if we take the Bloch group $B(\mathbb{F})$ generated by elements of $\mathbb{F}$, this is, by work of Suslin, essentially equal to $K_3(\mathbb{F})$.

To summarize, the connection between the identity, the cohomology of $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$, and the Bloch group is well understood, see some papers by Walter Neumann. For the connection between the Bloch group $B(\mathbb{F})$ and $K_3(\mathbb{F})$, see papers of Suslin. The connection with motives is more speculative, but here you should look at some papers of Goncharov.

(There are some generalizations/connections to higher regulators for K-groups, but this is a very nice example to understand, being both somewhat accessible yet still very interesting.)

Comment: Thanks. Very nice answer! I will try to add the hyperbolic-geometry tag to the question.

Answer (score 8):

There is a remarkable article, "The remarkable dilogarithm," J. Math. Phys. Sci. 22 (1988),   131--145, by Don Zagier, which was recently reprinted and updated as "The dilogarithm function" (63 pages!) in one of the collections by Springer Verlag.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little book by Bloch, called Higher regulators, algebraic K-theory, and zeta functions of elliptic curves. It was published quite recently but is based on a famous lecture series from the late 70s or so. He treats the dilog specifically, rather than the more general polylog framework referred to by Rob. See in particular chapter 6.

Answer (score 1):

For the relation to motives (and K-theory), I'd suggest the first several article of Motives, volume 2 (the proceedings of the Seattle conference [link text](http://ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=pspumseries&ikey=PSPUM-55-2-S)). I don't really know this stuff, but it is apparently believed that the polylogarithms are related to the "higher regulators" from K-theory to Deligne cohomology. These regulators are supposed to help explain the values of L-functions of motives at integers. Apparently the usual logarithm occurs in the first chern class of a variety (and the regulators are thought of as generalizations of chern class, or something). Good luck.